# Why is the list value not reflected when I change the value by slicing the 2D list?

Tags: python, list, slice

I created ***2D list*** and changed the value of the list by slicing the list.

```
mylist=[[1,3,5],[3,5,7],[5,7,9]]
mylist[1:2]=[300,400]
mylist
```

I expected mylist to return `[[1,3,5],[300,400],[5,7,9]]`, but it returned `[[1,3,5],300,400,[5,7,9]]`.

Can anyone explain this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### You needed an extra pair of `[]`

Do this to get what you wanted:

```
mylist=[[1,3,5],[3,5,7],[5,7,9]]
mylist[1:2]=[[300,400]]
mylist
print(mylist)
```

Reasons:

#### To put a single value into a single position in an array, do this:

```
mylist=[[1,3,5],[3,5,7],[5,7,9]]
mylist[1]=300
mylist
print(mylist)
```

#### To put a list into a *single position* in an array, do this:

```
mylist=[[1,3,5],[3,5,7],[5,7,9]]
mylist[1]=[300,400]
mylist
print(mylist)
```

#### You were telling it to put a list of items into a *list of positions*

This piece of code highlighted describes a *list* of positions, albeit containing only one position, namely [1].

```
mylist=[[1,3,5],[3,5,7],[5,7,9]]

###########
mylist[1:2]=[300,400]
###########

mylist
print(mylist)
```

Python was doing what it should when you tell it to replace a list of *x* positions with a list of *y* values: delete *x* positions and insert *y* positions, i.e. change the length of the list if x != y.

What you need to do was to tell it to replace a *list of positions* with a *list of length one* (that happened to contain a list of two values).

Thus you needed the right hand side to be a list of length one:

```
            #############
mylist[1:2]=[ [300,400] ]
            #############
```